# Where is 'required' actually added to the DOM?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm struggling to understand how angularjs modifies the DOM, specifically in regards to the `ng-required` directive. The ng-required directive ([from GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c8d349870812284a82896087c05c2d19c8f5cdfd/src/ng/directive/validators.js)):

```
var requiredDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      ctrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !attr.required || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
      };

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  };
};
```

I've placed breakpoints in the functions with Chrome's debugger, and from what I can tell, this code does not actually modify the required value in the DOM, yet I can see that `required="required"` gets added and removed from the input element. Where in the angularjs source code does the actual modification of the DOM happen?

A simple test form:

```
        <form>
          <label>Test Select</label>
          <select ng-model="testSelect" ng-required="testIsRequired">
            <option>val 1</option>
            <option>val 2</option>
          </select>
          <label>Required
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testIsRequired" />
          </label>

          <label>Output</label>
          <p>
            Test is required:  {{testIsRequired}}
          </p>
          <p>
            Select Value: {{testSelect}}
          </p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get a breakpoint in the right place. AngularJS sets a default link function for the 'boolean' attributes ('required', 'disabled', etc.), with the exception of the 'multiple' attribute.

The boolean attributes are watched, and the `$set` method of `attr` is used to change the DOM.

It seems like the actual `requiredDirective` in the question only deals with updating validation when the ng-required value is changed.

The relevant code (again, from [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1e9eadcd72dbbd5c67dae8328a63e535cfa91ff9/src/ng/directive/attrs.js)):

```
var ngAttributeAliasDirectives = {};

// boolean attrs are evaluated
forEach(BOOLEAN_ATTR, function(propName, attrName) {
  // binding to multiple is not supported
  if (propName === 'multiple') return;

  function defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function ngBooleanAttrWatchAction(value) {
      attr.$set(attrName, !!value);
    });
  }

  var normalized = directiveNormalize('ng-' + attrName);
  var linkFn = defaultLinkFn;

  if (propName === 'checked') {
    linkFn = function(scope, element, attr) {
      // ensuring ngChecked doesn't interfere with ngModel when both are set on the same input
      if (attr.ngModel !== attr[normalized]) {
        defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr);
      }
    };
  }

  ngAttributeAliasDirectives[normalized] = function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 100,
      link: linkFn
    };
  };
});
```